# First order, first degree differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$xdy-ydx=x \sqrt{x^2-y^2}dy$$

I tried extracting an integrating factor and failed, nor did other methods work. I'm thinking hyperbolic substitutions should work, or is easier then it seems?

Comment: How about $y=x\sin\theta?$

Comment: Nada . Stuck at the very last step . I get : cos(theta)d(theta)=cos(theta)sin(theta)dx + x.cos^2(theta)d(theta)...teh rhs term should have come out to be an exact form . I might be doing somethign wrong. thanks for the ehlp mate !

Comment: Putting $y=x\sin\theta,$ and on simplification we get $$d\theta=dy$$

Answer (score 1):

we have :

$\frac{xdy}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}-\frac{ydx}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}=xdy$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-(\frac{y}{x}})^2}-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\frac{x}{y})^2-1}}=xdy$ ($1$)

Put $u=\frac{y}{x}$ so $y=ux $ which gives $dy=xdu+udx$ ($2$)

Substituting ($2$) into ($1$) gives us

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{xdu+udx}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\frac{dx}{\sqrt{(\frac{1}{u})^2-1}}=x(xdu+udx)$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{xdu+udx}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\frac{udx}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=x(xdu+udx)$

$ \Leftrightarrow\frac{xdu+udx}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}-\frac{udx}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=x(xdu+udx)$

$ \Leftrightarrow\frac{xdu}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=x(xdu+udx)$

$ \Leftrightarrow\frac{xdu}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=x(xdu+udx)$

$\Rightarrow \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=xdu+udx$

$\Rightarrow \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=d(ux)$

$\Rightarrow \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=dy$

$\Rightarrow \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}=\int dy$

So, $y=arcsinu+C=arcsin(\frac{y}{x})+C$

Comment: Thanks ! Thanks everyone !